# How to control an OpenGL projection matrix with iPhone accelerometer/compass values?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, accelerometer, compass-geolocation, augmented-reality

Is there any ready made class/formula somewhere I can use it for control my viewpoint by accelerometer's/compass's XYZ?

I want to achieve the same view control like [acrossair](http://www.acrossair.com/acrossair_app_augmented_reality_browser_for_iPhone_3GS.htm) uses.

I have the parts (OpenGL space, filtered accel-, compass values, and a cubic panoramic view mapped to a cube around my origin).

Can somebody suggest me where to start at least?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got into the problem since, so the posts about the steps of the solution can be followed here:

[xCode - augmented reality](http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/categories/xCode_-_augmented_reality/) at [gotoandplay.freeblog.hu](http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/)

A brief sketch about the whole process below:
[How to get the transformation matrix from the raw iPhone sensor (accelerometer, magnetometer) data http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/files/2010/06/iPhoneDeviceOrientationTransformationMatrix-thumb.jpg](http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/files/2010/06/iPhoneDeviceOrientationTransformationMatrix-thumb.jpg)

Comment: links are dead, have another source?

Comment: Aww, sorry, the blog engine just shut down, the original files are on a distant hard drive. I'll contact the blog site, and get back to you. They have another valuable data sunken.

Answer (score 2):

If all you are looking for is a means of rotating the model view matrix for your scene, you could look at the source code to my [Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules) application or an even simpler [cube example](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/CubeExample.zip) that I wrote for my [iPhone development class](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032).  Both contain code to incrementally rotate the model view matrix in response to touch input, so you would just need to replace the touch input with accelerometer values.

Additionally, Apple's [GLGravity](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/GLGravity/Introduction/Intro.html) sample application does something very similar to what you want.

Comment: Ye, I can rotate object/camera. My main problem is to combine somehow the accelerometer values with the compass values, and tackle the upside-down cases. GLGravity uses only accelerometer, so its only the half of the picture.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply anyway. You're the only who tried to help so far.